# jQuery select a option on all select fields with shortcut

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have a html form page that has a bunch of select options that look like below:

```
<select name="newCodes[123][10][code]">
<option value="">--</option>
<option value="53">A</option>
<option value="54">B</option>
<option value="55">C</option>
<option value="55">#</option>
</select>
```

The difference between every select element is that the 123 and the 10 values change. The option values are all the same. Is it possible with jQuery to select a certain option on all newCodes select elements? For example if I wanted everything to be # then I could press something like ctrl and # etc?

Thank you.

Comment: how about `select all <select> where the name attribute started with newCodes` -> [`$("select[name^=newCodes]")`](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/)

Comment: Is it possible...certainly. Have you done any research at all on this? If you have then show what you have tried. Otherwise have a read through [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I solved this by creating a dedicated select menu with an ID of allCodes like this:

```
<select name="" id="allCodes">
```

Then i assigned all the looping select elements a class of userCodes like this. I used a class so that they can all be referred to by the same name. Whereas an id has to be unique to each element.

```
<select name="newCodes[123][10][code]" class="userCodes">
```

I then have the following jQuery code that duplicates whatever I select from the allCodes drop-down to all the userCodes looping drop-down menus.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('#allCodes').on('change', function(){
  $(".userCodes option").each(function(){
  if ($(this).text() == $('#allCodes option:selected').text()) {
   $(this).attr('selected',true);
  }
  });
 });
});
```

[Here's a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8jLeagh3/)